# 「よかったでした」？ Is this correct?

Tags: grammar

From [this goo post](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/922050.html):

> 確かに顔を見たことはありませんでした。
>   でも普通アパートって隣の顔を見たり、接点持ったりとかあまりないですよね？
>   ただ今回は相手の方もうるさくないと思って聞いてたそうで、また性格のよさそうな人だったので、**良かったでした**。

Is this a mistake, or is this actually grammatically correct? If so, what would be the difference between this and simply "よかったです"?

Comment: It's a simple mistake. As you guessed, 良かったです is the correct sentence.

Comment: 「楽しかったでした」などをググると結構使ってる人いますね…「～かったでした」は鹿児島弁だという話も…(鹿児島の人は「楽しかったです」を「楽しいでした」や、ときに「楽しかったでした」と言ってしまうらしい…)

Comment: To close voters: I don't think this is a bad question. The question won 3 upvotes and 134 views, which is relatively high in Japanese language site with smaller user base as compared with EL&U site. A down vote and close vote often discourage the question / answer poster. It's better for you to refrain from giving a jump-the-gun negative vote without thinking  over that there are  people with various level of  learning of Japanese language which is difficult for non-native speakers and  living experience in Japan.

Comment: Correction: there are people with various level of learning of Japanese language which is difficult for non-native speakers and living experience in Japan.⇒there are people with various level of learning of Japanese language which is difficult for non-native speakers with scanty living experience in Japan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

良かった、良かったです、良かったと思います are proper Japanese. 良かったでした is a very awkward and wrong expression, even though it's could be a joking way of saying.
I strongly recommend you not to use such a damned expression, unless you wish to look like a 変な外人.