# 「楽しいでした？」- clarifications about this conjugation

Tags: conjugations, adjectives

I browsed around this website ([here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3766/%E3%81%84-adjective-conjugation-%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99-vs-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/34199/%E3%82%88%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A7%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-is-this-correct)) as well as around the [internet](http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/4265690.html) but could not come up with a satisfactory answer, or at least well related to my case (though I might have missed that point).

Simply, the other day a quite old lady (over 70 I think) asked me 「楽しいでした？」 at the end of a shodou class.

My question is, is this just a polite version of 「楽しかった？」that somehow confuses me? In such case would that be more polite than 「楽しかったですか」?

Or is it just a way older people might talk sometimes? At the moment I heard it my first thought was whether she thought I could not speak Japanese and put it in a wrong but easy to understand form (as if she thought I might not know how to conjugate an いーadjective properly).

Maybe it's just a silly question but right there on the spot it confused me a bit and I would like some clarifications. Thanks.

Comment: Next time ask her maybe ?

Comment: Eheh good point, on the spot I didn't think about asking.

Comment: I never expect a native speaker of Japanese to say "楽しいでした".  "she thought I could not speak Japanese and put it in a wrong but easy to understand form" +1 for your guess. One form of Pidgin, I'd say.

Comment: Are you sure you just didn't mishear 「楽しい**ん**でした？」

Comment: Was there any hesitation in their voice? It could also be possible that the past tense was an afterthought or a similar mistake. I often find myself incapable of speaking my own native language properly (especially when tired!)

Comment: 方言という可能性はないんでしょうか・・

Comment: @istrasci well, I couldn't swear there was no ん in the middle, but i don't think there was. Anyway, in case it was with the ん, wouldn't that sound strange as well? Or would it be perfectly normal?

Comment: @BDawg As I could not remember about the ん, I could not really say about any hesitation. Good point though.

Comment: @chocolate そうですね、私もその可能性もあると思っていた。今度直接聞いた方がいいかな。
Anyway, as I thought based on these comments it seems that the expression itself is indeed strange. Thanks everyone for the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is that she asked 楽しいでしたか？
In that case, it might sound natural, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

I think it pays to bear in mind that people who speak a language at a native level often use the language in ways that we would consider as improper, on a grammatical level(e.g. how someone could be saying the most profound things, but wrt it ot lyk dis, bcuz dis is hw dey grw up wrtng out their thoughts n feelings). Grammar is still important, but as long as you can understand them, everything else is gravy